# Section title not wrapping

Tags: objective-c, xcode, ios5.1

I am trying to wrap my section header and `UILineBreakModeWordWrap` is not helping. Any idea what I am doing wrong?

```
- (UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
{ 
    UIView *rOView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10,0,300,60)] ;   
    UILabel *sectionLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero];
    sectionLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    sectionLabel.font = [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:18];
    sectionLabel.frame = CGRectMake(70,18,200,20);
    sectionLabel.text =  @"A really really long text A really really long text A really really long text";
    sectionLabel.textColor = [UIColor blueColor];
    sectionLabel.numberOfLines = 0;
    sectionLabel.lineBreakMode = UILineBreakModeWordWrap;

    [roView addSubview:sectionLabel];
    return roView; 
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've not given the label a meaningful frame - only CGRectZero. After setting up your label, call `-sizeToFit` on it, like so:

```
UILabel *sectionLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero];
sectionLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
sectionLabel.font = [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:18];
sectionLabel.frame = CGRectMake(70,18,200,20);
sectionLabel.text =  @"A really really long text A really really long text A really really long text";
sectionLabel.textColor = [UIColor blueColor];
sectionLabel.numberOfLines = 0;
sectionLabel.lineBreakMode = UILineBreakModeWordWrap;
[sectionLabel sizeToFit];
```

Edit: I see now that you did actually set the label frame. But the height is too short to display all the text.

Comment: Thank You. It worked. But for cell.textlabel, I didnot call the method sizeToFit, but is working. Is it because it is a textLabel? and textLabel and UILabel is little different. Appreciate your inputs.

Comment: Maybe the cell is sizing its label behind the scenes. You assigned your section label a height of 20, which is too little to display the three lines of text you needed.

Comment: Yup. Fixed it. I reduced the bottom (x,y) of the rectangle and top right is calculated based on tableView.bounds.size.width-10 since my section contents varies. Thanks again